# check variable null is not in stdout_lines

Tags: ansible

I have this output:

```yaml
- name: list image exist on nexu
  debug:  
    var: check_image_exist.stdout_lines
  tags:
   - check_image_exist
```

```
ok: [workstation] => {
    "check_image_exist.stdout_lines": [
        "{",
        "  \"items\" : [ {",
        "    \"downloadUrl\" : \"http://cluster.repo.local:8081/repository/docker_hosted/v2/-/blobs/sha256:aeab776c48375e1a61810a0a5f59e982e34425ff505a01c2b57dcedc6799c17b\",",
        "    \"repository\" : \"docker_hosted\",",
        "    \"format\" : \"docker\",",
        "    \"checksum\" : {",
        "    },",
        "    \"contentType\" : \"application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip\",",
       
        "  } ],",
        "  \"continuationToken\" : null",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

I need to check that `continuationToken` is not null. When I use `check_image_exist.stdout_lines.continuationToken` I am told that the variable is not defined!
How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a JSON in the return of your command but a string representation of a JSON, you need to:

1. Use the [`stdout` property](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout) of tour dictionary, so you have the whole string and not a list of strings, like the one provided by [`stdout_lines`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout-lines)
2. Use [`from_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) in order to have that switch that string to a JSON
3. Then your expected behaviour kicks in

So, all together:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: (check_image_exist.stdout | from_json).continuationToken
```

Comment: not work
`ok: [workstation] => {
    "(check_image_exist.stdout | to_json).continuationToken": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}`

Comment: `from_json`* my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data

```yaml
  data:
    continuationToken: null
    items:
    - checksum: {}
      contentType: application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip
      downloadUrl: http://cluster.repo.local:8081/repository/docker_hosted/v2/-/blobs/sha256:aeab776c48375e1a61810a0a5f59e982e34425ff505a01c2b57dcedc6799c17b
      format: docker
      repository: docker_hosted
```

---

Q: ***"Check continuationToken is not null."***

A: Use test [*none*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.none). The task below will be skipped

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: continuationToken is not null
      when: data.continuationToken is not none
```

---

The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: continuationToken is null
      when: data.continuationToken is none
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: continuationToken is null
```

---

Use *ternary* to evaluate both options

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ data.continuationToken is none|
                 ternary('continuationToken is null',
                         'continuationToken is not null') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: continuationToken is null
```

---

See how the test works

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "'{{ item.value }}' is none: {{ item.value is none }}"
      loop:
        - value:
        - value: null
        - value: foo
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': None}) => 
  msg: ''''' is none: True'
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': None}) => 
  msg: ''''' is none: True'
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': 'foo'}) => 
  msg: '''foo'' is none: False'
```